# Do 15-25% of all computer users worldwide (both vocational and recreational) have some computer-related injury (CRI)?

Tags: computers, healthcare

This [news article](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2006-08-27/news/27459834_1_cri-computer-workstation) from the [The Economic Times](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economic_Times) claims that:

> 15-25% of all computer users worldwide (both vocational and recreational) are estimated to have computer-related injuries (CRI).

The same, unreferenced claim is echoed [on many websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+survey+of+500+software+professionals+at+Hyderabad+in+2000+revealed+that+over+50%5C%25+had+symptoms+of+established+RSI.&oq=A+survey+of+500+software+professionals+at+Hyderabad+in+2000+revealed+that+over+50%5C%25+had+symptoms+of+established+RSI.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.159j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). Do 15-25% of all computer users worldwide (both vocational and recreational) have some computer-related injury (CRI)?

Comment: You seem to be equating CRI with RSI. Isn't RSI just one of many CRI?

Comment: @RobWatts Thanks, good point, yes from my understanding RSI is just one of many CRI. Question edited!